# PDFBOX page to image produce blurry image if the page dimensions are low

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

my task is to convert pdf files into images (usually PNG), I encounter situations when the page dimension is low (612,792) the rendered image quality is poor even scale rendering or DPI api's "pdfRenderer.renderImage(pageNo, 2)"

**20.0.20 **version is used.****

This is how it looks using **pdf viewer** :
[image]

Same snippet from the rendered image :
[image]

zooming in the pdf viewer :
[image]

zooming the rendered image result the following :

[image]

is there any way to create better image quality ??

thanks

Comment: Please share the file... also mention what PDFBox version you are using. 2.0.20 has a bug with certain files, so compare with 2.0.19. The rendering quality should be better as the scale goes up. (4 is 288 dpi)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank for your quick reply. the version i'm using is 2.0.20. indeed downgrading to 20.0.19 solve the problem. i can't share the original file as it contain sensitive data. anyhow, I will stick with 20.0.19 for now.

Comment: Then the bug is likely solved in 2.0.21, which will come out soon, please try it  https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.21-SNAPSHOT/  here's the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4863

Comment: indeed the problem is solved in version 2.0.21. verified by pdfbox-app-2.0.21-20200801.094822-151.jar. thanks for your help.

Comment: Please click on the checkmark of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of blurry images in 2.0.20 has been solved in 2.0.21, released in August 2020. The problem was fixed in the issue [PDFBOX-4863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4863) (the title is misleading, the problem is not just related to fonts).

Comment: @Z.H. Please accept the answer otherwise this can not be used to indicate duplicates of this error...